# how can i export oracle tables that have a prefix in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I know the command line to export is:

expdp '/ as sysdba' directory=EXPORT DUMPFILE=FILE.DMP TABLES=nametable

```
There is such a thing as query type:

export all tables starting with the prefix "table_"
```

```
There is such a thing as query type:

export all tables starting with the prefix "table_"
```

Comment: Do you mean all the table that start with `table_`, without having to list them all? If so you could maybe use [the `include` option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-A3C5241C-098C-42FF-B7D1-6018B2ABC282).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve this whit the command include:

expdp hr INCLUDE=TABLE: like('g%') DUMPFILE=dpump_dir1:exp_inc.dmp NOLOGFILE=YES